# Manipulate multiple check boxes by ID using unobtrusive Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to be able to select multiple check boxes `onmouseover`, but instead of applying  `onmouseover` to every individual box, I've been trying to work out how to do so by manipulating check boxes by ID instead, although I'm not sure where to go from using `getElementById`. So instead of what you see below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
     var Toggle = true;

  var Highlight=false;
  function handleKeyPress(evt) {
     var nbr;
     if (window.Event) nbr = evt.which;
     else nbr = event.keyCode;
     if(nbr==16)Highlight=true;
     return true;
  }

  function MakeFalse(){Highlight=false;}

  function SelectIt(X){
      if(X.checked && Toggle)X.checked=false;
      else X.checked=true;
  }
function ChangeText()
{
    var test1 = document.getElementById("1");
    test1.innerHTML = "onmouseover=SelectIt(this)"
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="A">
<input type="checkbox" name="C1" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="1"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C2" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="2"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C3" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="3"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C4" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" checked="" disabled="disabled" id="4"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C5" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="5"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C6" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="6"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C7" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="7"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C8" onmouseover="SelectIt(this)" id="8"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to apply the `onmousover` effect to an array of check boxes like this:

```
<form name="A">
<input type="checkbox" name="C1" id="1"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C2" id="2"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C3" id="3"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C4" checked="" disabled="disabled" id="4"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C5" id="5"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C6" id="6"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C7" id="7"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C8" id="8"><br>
</form>
```

After trying the search feature of Stack Overflow and looking around on Google I haven't been able to a find a solution that makes sense to me thus far, although I'm still in the process of learning so I fear I might be trying to do something too advanced for my level of knowledge.

Comment: Have you looked into a javascript Libaray such as jQuery or YUI?

Comment: I recommend you try questions like this at codereview.stackexchange.com since the questions generically on style, without a specific optimization.  Lasering in on something specific like this could make it more productive on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your inputs' event to make unobstrusive JavaScript. Agents that can't do JavaScript will just ignore `onmouseover` attribute. And since I hope you generate checkboxes on the server-side in the loop, there's no need to fear copypasting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider grabbing jQuery for anything client side. For example, your question can be very easily modeled in jQuery and with extremely less code:

```
$(':checkbox').mouseover(function()
{
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

This grabs all the check boxes on your page, attaches a mouseover event to them, and then when a mouse over occurs, it simply toggles the state of the checked attribute on the element.